# How to create my own function with { } in PHP

Tags: php, function

I want to create my own function `loop()`:

```
loop($x,$y){
    //do something
}
```

it should work like for, foreach operators:

```
$y=count($array); 
for($x=0; $x<$y; $x++){ 
     //do something 
}
```

How to create functions like this with `{ }` in PHP? (NOT a regular function)

Comment: what do you mean by {} syntax?

Comment: I think he just means, how do you create a function in php.

Comment: @MasterPeter {} like in for(){  } function

Comment: The problem with anonymous functions is that you have to write them every time you want to use them. If you write a function once, give it a name. The only real use I see for anonymous functions is to add more parameters to a function with function calls like array_map or array_walk.

Comment: he just worded it wrong, he means a new language construct. Why do you want to do that Colargol?

Comment: Probably because he learned to program in Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing which you can if you are really serious about your function/s you can write it a php extension which will you some flexibility...http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/1021 I must warn you though..it's not as easy....

Answer (score 13):

You can't.

Constructs like for or foreach are part of php syntax.

If you want to create regular function just use function keyword:

```
function some_func($x, $y)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 5):

At a more advanced level, you could create a class and iterate that, in which you can pretty much change the execution flow *during* execution (while iterating).

Here's the docs: http://php.net/iterator

Answer (score 2):

There will be lambda functions - that's what you want to do - in PHP 6.
Right now you have to stick with "normal" functions.

Comment: "in PHP 6".  in PHP 5.3 actually.

Comment: If this is the right answer, we need a different question. For the question as is (how to create a function), the answer by empi is correct.

Comment: @OIS he said "create a function with { } NOT a regular function" meaning EXACTLY that he wants lambda functions.  +1.

Comment: You are correct. The question could be a bit better though. :)

Comment: if lambda function in php are to be like in python (i.e. anonymous functions) then this DOES NOT answer the question. He wants to create a new construct (like the for loop), not a function.